# Create columns dynamically in data frame R and populate based on other column condition

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am a beginner in R.
I have a data frame like this -

```
df <- data.frame(CustomerID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
                , ProductPurchased = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B')
                    , PurchaseNumber = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2))

df
CustomerID ProductPurchased PurchaseNumber
1                A              1
1                B              2
2                B              1
2                A              2
2                C              3
3                C              1
3                B              2
```

PurchaseNumber indicates nth time purchase. Ex - 1 indicates First Purchase, 2 indicates Second purchase etc.

I would like to add a column say 'FirstPurchase' that would populate the ProductPurchased for the First Time for that Customer

```
CustomerID ProductPurchased PurchaseNumber  FirstPurchase
1                A              1               A
1                B              2               A
2                B              1               B
2                A              2               B
2                C              3               B
3                C              1               C
3                B              2               C
```

As a next step - 
I am looking to see if I could read the MAX(PurchaseNumber) and based on that 
dynamically create those many columns and each column should have the Product Purchased for that 
Customer.
Ex - Since the Max(PurchaseNumber) here is 3. It should create 3 columns (Not worried about naming them as First, Second, Third) like this -

```
CustomerID ProductPurchased PurchaseNumber  FirstPurchase   SecondPurchase      ThirdPurchase
1                A              1               A               B               NA
1                B              2               A               B               NA
2                B              1               B               A               C
2                A              2               B               A               C
2                C              3               B               A               C
3                C              1               C               B               NA
3                B              2               C               B               NA
```

I did try couple of things with the data.table -

```
dt <- data.table(df)

# this will give CustomerID and their first purchase
dt[PurchaseNumber == 1, 2, with = FALSE]
```

But how do I apply them to the rest of the columns?

Any help is appreciated. Even pointers what package should I look into would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: What does A B C refer to?

Comment: It seems that you could `merge` "df" and `reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "CustomerID", timevar = "PurchaseNumber")` by "CustomerID".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet for this is [tidyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/index.html):

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, PurchaseNumber, ProductPurchased)

# CustomerID 1 2    3
# 1          1 A B <NA>
# 2          2 B A    C
# 3          3 C B <NA>
```

Comment: This is cool. I can spread it and then left_join to get the desired result. Thank you @heathobrien. Appreciate your code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mouthful, but you can try something like:

```
library(splitstackshape)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
dcast(
  getanID(
    expandRows(DT[, count := max(PurchaseNumber), by = CustomerID], "count"), 
    c("CustomerID", "PurchaseNumber")),
  CustomerID + .id ~ PurchaseNumber, value.var = "ProductPurchased")
#    CustomerID .id 1 2  3
# 1:          1   1 A B NA
# 2:          1   2 A B NA
# 3:          2   1 B A  C
# 4:          2   2 B A  C
# 5:          2   3 B A  C
# 6:          3   1 C B NA
# 7:          3   2 C B NA
```

That seems to be a lot of redundant data though.

---

Steps involved:

1. Add a column indicating the max counts by CustomerID.
2. Use `expandRows` from my "splitstackshape" package to lengthen your `data.table`.
3. Use `getanID` to create a new indicator variable grouped by CustomerID and PurchaseNumber.
4. Use `dcast` to widen the long `data.table` you had just created.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you Ananda Mahto. However as you already mentioned there would be lot of redundant data created. Let me see if there is a good way to reduce redundancy. However really appreciate your code.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer as it has a lot of valuable information. And it does solve the issue I asked. However since I plan to use heathobrien's answer I accepted his.